# Sorting Variables C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I am trying to get a count from a list of 20 variables then sort the output in descending order in the form of a string.  Each time a person chooses a certain type of music, that type of music will ++ it's variable by one.  At the end of 10 days it needs to be sorted and output the type names in order. Here is a shorter example:

```
int rock;
int jazz;
int pop;

int count = 0;
int days = 0;

while(days < 10) {

cout << "Choose your style: " << "\n";
cout << "1. Rock" << "\n";
cout << "2. Jazz" << "\n";
cout << "3. Pop" << "\n";  
cin >> count; 

switch(count) {

    case 1:
    ++rock;
    break;

    case 2:
        ++jazz;
        break;

    case 3:
        ++pop;
        break;

}

++days
}

// Now sort the styles in order of most used???
// output based on that order ie:

cout << "You Love Pop Music most! Rock seems to be your next Favorite. \n";
cout << "You are not much of a jazz person.\n";
```

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you know about [if statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)?

Comment: BTW, Some of your variables are not initialized.

Comment: A [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) could be ued to do this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(rock>=jazz)
{
    if(rock>=pop)
    {
        // rock is biggest one
        std::cout << "You Love Rock Music most! ";
        if(jazz>=pop)
        {
            // rock>jazz>pop
            std::cout << "Jazz seems to be your next Favorite. \n";
            std::cout << "You are not much of a pop person.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            // rock>pop>jazz
            std::cout << "Pop seems to be your next Favorite. \n";
            std::cout << "You are not much of a jazz person.\n";
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        // pop is biggest one
        // pop>rock>jazz
        std::cout << "You Love Pop Music most! ";
        std::cout << "Rock seems to be your next Favorite. \n";
        std::cout << "You are not much of a jazz person.\n";
    }
}
else
{
    if(jazz>=pop)
    {
        // jazz is biggest one
        std::cout << "You Love Jazz Music most! ";
        if(rock>=pop)
        {
            // jazz>rock>pop
            std::cout << "Rock seems to be your next Favorite. \n";
            std::cout << "You are not much of a pop person.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            // jazz>pop>rock
            std::cout << "Pop seems to be your next Favorite. \n";
            std::cout << "You are not much of a rock person.\n";
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        // pop is biggest one
        // pop>jazz>rock
        std::cout << "You Love Pop Music most! ";
        std::cout << "Jazz seems to be your next Favorite. \n";
        std::cout << "You are not much of a pop person.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider adding some explanation to your code. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for helpful comment. Comment line is enough or write some sentences for explanation.